# Do I need to make draft in google play console before I use Fastlane

Tags: fastlane, google-play-console

Can you upload app in Fastlane command with android and Fastlane app in the google play console or I need to make draft in console before I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastlane unfortunately can not create an Android app from scratch, as it can with [`create_app_online` (formerly known as `produce`) for iOS](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/create_app_online/). Google just doesn't offer any API for that.

So yes, you have to at least create the app on the Google Play Console which usually includes uploading a first APK (so the Play Console knows about the package name [`com.example.app`] or your app) to one of the available lanes (which doesn't have to get published though).